# How to convert HTML to PDF using PHP?

Tags: php

I want to convert HTML with Google Charts reports to PDF,I used fpdf and other classes but I didnt get success.
please help me .

Comment: What do you mean *exactly* by saying that you "didn't get success"?

Comment: 100x duplicate: http://www.google.com/search?q=html+pdf+php+site:stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using HTML 2 PDF available from sourceforge [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/html2fpdf/)

Comment: That will hardly be able to deal with Google Charts report, will it?

Comment: @Pekka, I've not tried it but Google Charts gives us .png images, I guess it should be able to handle that.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try [dompdf](http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/)